# Retention Policy on SharePoint Online List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, retention

I have created a new connection in Records Management from Admin center. For a list, I have set the Retention Policy on **Item** Content type from *Information management policy settings* in List settings.

[image]

I did all these on last Friday but still the items are not moved and present in the same list.

Kindly assist me if I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, when we create a retention policy in SharePoint Online, there are two timer jobs "Expiration policy" and "Information management policy" in the system which run weekly automatically and update the policy for SharePoint Online site, after these two timer jobs run, the retention policy will apply to list.

We cannot run these timer jobs manually, please wait up to one week and check again.

Here it's the link to create Information Management Policies: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/create-info-mgmt-policies?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fcreate-and-apply-information-management-policies-8ccac9e4-3a50-49fa-a95b-d186032a6ee3